# Grab a query string and add the query string to the href in a Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, query-string

I'm trying to figure out how to grab a query string from the address bar and append it to links in a Wordpress post.  I don't want to use a plugin.  I would rather find away to do this without a plugin.  In non-wordpress pages, I use

```
. urldecode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) .
```

but php isn't allowed in posts and widgets in wordpress. How can I grab the query string and add it to the href in a Wordpress post?  Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php

    $parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    var_dump($parts, $parts['query']);

    //or you can always access parameters 
    var_dump($_GET);
```

If you can add a javascript to a page you can do:

```
function overwriteLinks () {
   var path = document.location.search;
   var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   for (i=0, l=links.length; i < l; i++) {
      var link = links[i];
      var newPath = link.href.replace(link.hash, '') + path + link.hash ;
      link.href = newPath;
   }
}

overwriteLinks ();
```

That would overwrite **all** links the way you want and preserve hash values as well

Comment: Thanks...  In wordpress, where do I add what you provided?  Also what do I add to the href in the wordpress post?

Comment: It is unclear on what and where you trying to achieve. So you would have to provide more information.

Comment: I'm trying to grab the query string from the address bar and append it to the links in a wordpress post. What can you not understand and I'll try to explain it clearer if I can.

Comment: Add an example on how you create link in WP

Comment: <a href="hello.php>hello</a>

Comment: And is it through form or a php file on server?

Comment: No the url query string is coming from outside of the wordpress page.  In the address bar, it could be domain.com/?thequerystring...... etc.   I want append the query string in the href like <a href=" domain.com/?thequerystring......"></a> so I need something like <a href=" domain.com/[thiisthestring]."></a>... Remember the string will be different so I cannot just add the string to the href.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104679/discussion-between-e-p-and-user5310505).

Comment: @user5310505 Update my answer

Comment: Javascript would be great to BUT in a post and widgets js, jquery, php cannot be used.  Only html and css.  Unless I download a plugin which I do not  want to do.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using shortcode?  Anyone?  If it is can you provide an example?